# Can't render Svg icons in custom React Native Component

Tags: javascript, react-native, icons

I'm having problems rendering an icon I'm supplying through a prop in a custom component. Here is my custom component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

export class MoreIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.topViewStyle}>
            <View style={styles.circleStyle}>
                <Image source={this.props.iconSource} style={styles.iconStyle} />
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.moreIconText}>{this.props.iconText}</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    topViewStyle: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    moreIconText: {
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#fff',
        lineHeight: 1.17,
        height: 14,
    },
    iconStyle: {
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
    },
    circleStyle: {
        width: 58,
        height: 58,
        borderRadius: 50,
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
        borderWidth: 2,
    }
});
```

The problem is, when I supply a source attribute in the component like this:

```
<MoreIcon iconText='Home' iconSource={require('../../assets/icons/dashboard.svg')} />
```

Nothing shows up in the circle, and it looks like this:
[image]

**What am I doing wrong to where the prop I'm supplying doesn't show up in the `MoreIcon` tab? (the path is correct fyi)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert your SVGs to be compatible with the [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) library. Luckily, there are a few great examples on the [Usage section](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#usage) of the readme.

There's also a [great example on Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@msand/react-native-svg-example)

After you've converted them, you'll be able to `import` them as normal constants.

**EDIT:**

As per Adam's comment below, using the [`react-native-svg-uri`](https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri) library now seems like the simpler approach to the SVG problem.

Comment: 100%, that was the problem. I had no idea that SVGs didn't render on React Native. I've used this library from Github (that looks pretty good) https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri to get my files to render! It was plug and play!

Comment: @AdamMcGurk awesome! I didn't even know that existed, but I might try that the next time I run into this issue myself. I've added the link you shared in case anyone else needs an alternative solution.